# Python-- can I fasten a data frame work using double keyed dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I need to store data row by row, and then query the data very fast (close to a billion of rows), I am using data frame:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,2,1,2],'B':[3,4,6,2,4], 'value':range(10, 15)})
```

-- I can insert into it row by row as I need to calculate each row, by using e.g., `df.append({'A':3, 'B':6, 'value':20},ignore_index=True)`

-- I need to be able to query on 'A' or on 'B', and get the other column and the value

However, this is slow. I was thinking of creating a double keyed dictionary, the inserting procedure did turn out faster, but how can i query it using only one key? So if i want to get all the first key is 2 for example?

```
    keyed_dic = keyed_dic = ({(0, 3): 10, (1, 4): 11, (2, 6): 12,
         (1, 2): 13, (2, 4): 14})
```

Am I even on the right track to try to use double keyed dictionary to faster a data frame procedure? Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: How do you calculate your data and what is your input data? If you want to speed it up you should find a way how to proceed your data in vectorized form.

Comment: Thanks, I was inspired by your comment, and changed the calculation ways. It turned out much faster.